# How to test initialization values of new action with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In my Ruby on Rails app I have an action `copy` that copies an `invoice` and renders its values to the frontend in a `new` action.

It works but I am finding it hard to test:

```
describe 'GET #copy' do

  before :each do
    @invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice, :date => Date.yesterday)
  end

  it "renders the :new template" do # this works
    get :copy, :id => @invoice
    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end

  it "sets the correct date" do
    get :copy, :id => @invoice
    expect(new_invoice.date).to eql(@invoice.date) # what I had in mind...
  end

end
```

I would simply like to test if the `date` gets copied correctly and is shown in the form. Will I have to save the new invoice first in order to test that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def copy
   @new_invoice
  end
end
```

Use `assigns` for testing instance variables inside your controller, like that `expect(assigns(:new_invoice).date).to eql(@invoice.date)`
For latest RSpec version, need install `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` for using `assigns` method